# MethodAccessException in Asp.net mvc-5 application when Uploading on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created a simple mvc-5 application with few pages in visual studio 2013. In dev, environment, it works fine but when I upload it to GoDaddy server it throws the following exception

> [MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method
>   'Vertance.MvcApplication.Application_Start()' to access security
>   critical method 'System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()'
>   failed.

When I check the version information on my local machine it shows following

> .NET framework versions: 4.0.30319
>   Asp.Net Version: 4.0.30319.34209

On server the version information is as following

> .Net Framework Version: 4.0.30319 (same as on local machine)
>   Asp.Net Version: 4.0.30319.34280  (different from local machine)

What could be the problem? Why this is happening?

**Edit 1:** I also put following attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs file

```
[assembly: SecurityCritical()]
```

but it did not work either.

Comment: It looks like GoDaddy misconfigured security settings.

Answer (score 5):

The problem solved by adding `Trust` element in `web.config` under `system.web` settings like

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full"/>
     .....
     ......
  </system.web>
```